# how to set type 'Sets' to orginate()

Tags: taquito

in smartpy,

```
self.init(used = sp.set(t = sp.TSignature))
```

in taquito

```
await Tezos.wallet.originate({
      code: contractJson,
      storage: {
        used: [],
      } })
```

> TezosOperationError {   errors: [
> {
> kind: 'permanent',
> id: 'proto.006-PsCARTHA.michelson_v1.ill_formed_type',
> identifier: 'storage',
> ill_formed_expression: [Array],
> location: 54
> },
> {
> kind: 'permanent',
> id: 'proto.006-PsCARTHA.michelson_v1.comparable_type_expected',
> location: 76,
> wrong_type: [Object]
> }   ],   name: 'TezosOperationError',   id: 'proto.006-PsCARTHA.michelson_v1.comparable_type_expected',   kind:
> 'permanent',   message: '(permanent)
> proto.006-PsCARTHA.michelson_v1.comparable_type_expected' }

this is not working, how to set type 'Sets'?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is correct for Taquito, you declare a `set` as a JavaScript array.
The error seems to be coming from the fact that sets [can only hold comparable values](https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com/#types) and you try to use it with cryptographic signatures, which is not a comparable type.

Comment: They're not comparable until proposal 008 to be precise.